# MSB1003 when building ASP with Jenkins

Tags: c#, asp.net, jenkins, tfs, msbuild

I am using Jenkins as a Windows Service with MSBuild to try and build an ASP project, but I get the following error after Jenkins have fetched all the source files from TFS:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The
>   current working directory does not contain a project or solution
>   file.

I have 3 projects in my solution. One that is ASP, one that is C# only and one that is a Database project. I have already set in my Solution that the ASP project should be the startup one but I guess I need to include the information somewhere else?

I don't quite understand where it wants me to set the project or solution file to make this work ._.

I have other projects from Colleagues at work as well whose projects are compiled and analyzed just fine. One of them is a heavy ASP.NET and Sharepoint project so not sure what gives.

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that the solution file cannot be found.

Comment: The path you must be supplying to the `MSBUILD` needs to be checked. you would probably find it as incorrect in the logs

Comment: It's weird though. I don't actually specify a path to MSBuild in the other projects. Jenkins do these things on it's own. This is the only thing I do `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:rebuild` in an execute Windows batch command because otherwise I couldn't run SonarQube analysis.

Comment: Bah christ I figured it out. The problem was my path to TFS. I had the right folder but I needed to go one level deeper in the folder to get the actual files and the solution file. So I guess you guys were partially right. Thanks :D